# After upgrading Excel 2010->2013, PowerPivot model cannot refresh connections

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013, powerpivot

I recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 2013. In order to modify my 2010 PowerPivot-enabled workbooks, I followed in-Excel upgrade process for the data model which reported a successful upgrade at completion. After restarting Excel, however, my newly-upgraded data model cannot connect to any previously-established data sources. Here is an example of an update to a look-up table, stored in an `.xlsx` file on a network drive, failing:

[image: failed]

After verifying network connectivity, existence of the file and permission to open it, I attempted to use PowerPivot's built-in test for connectivity, which SUCCEEDED:

[image: success]

I would prefer to not rebuild this design from scratch in 2013. What could be causing this refresh error?

Comment: Did you figure this out? You might consider posting this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks for checking-in on this lol, I unfortunately rebuilt from scratch... Bummer alert!